# macOS Big Sur Dictionary.app doesn't use system proxy

Tags: dictionary, proxy, big-sur

When using Wikipedia in Dictionary.app on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, Dictionary.app sends HTTPS requests to `*.b.akamaiedge.net` and is not utilizing system proxy (HTTP or socks5). How do I fix this?

Comment: Whoa, another person actually ran into this weird edge case! I have confirmed that Dictionary also blatantly ignores the system proxy for Wikipedia access on 10.6 (Snow Leopard), 10.9 (Mavericks), and 10.14 (Mojave), and presumably does so on every OS in between. Notably, Hopper makes it seem like Dictionary is reading a Boolean key suspiciously named `DCSDisableProxyForWikipediaAccess` from somewhere, but nothing I set via `defaults write` seems to have any effect!

Comment: @Wowfunhappy You should be able to set it via `defaults write -g`, but either way that key does not actually control proxy behavior. Instead it controls whether the requests are sent to "http://lookup-api.apple.com/en.wikipedia.org..." or just to en.wikipedia.org directly.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy The actual connection is done via `NSURLConnection` and does not really seem out of the ordinary. `NSUrlConnection` should honor the system proxy. The only thing I can think of is that because it accesses `http://...` which 307 redirects to the HTTPS version, somehow it doesn't honor the https proxy in that case.

Comment: Oh apparently that networking code in the main dictionary app is never used. The real thing is in DictionaryServices.framework. It uses CFHTTP which bypasses system proxy: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/69452

Comment: Also for an authoritative source see: https://opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-128.2/Headers/CFHTTPStream.h.auto.html "HTTP proxies are not applied automatically."

I guess if you wanted to patch it yourself you could use dyld injection and overwrite "CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest"  to always set system proxy before returning the read stream.

Comment: @1110101001 Thank you, this has been bothering me for weeks! I'm trying to revive the Dictionary app (for Wikipedia) on OS X 10.9. The OS doesn't support the modern SSL cipher suites now required by Wikipedia, which means I need to stick a proxy in the middle. Looks like I'll need to try writing a small SIMBL plugin...

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I'm not sure if SIMBL plugin is the best way. Because the methods in question are not objective-C methods, you can't just swizzle them. Ideally you would use ld_preload to replace CFReadStream with a wrapper that sets the proxy before returning the result. It will break code-signing (probably to no ill-effect once you resign yourself), but you can set LD_PRELOAD in the info plist so it's seamless.

Comment: SIMBL plugins are I think loaded after dyld finishes its business, so it's going to be messier. If you need to use SIMBL, you can do function hooking (https://github.com/Zeex/subhook) to shim the original.

Comment: Alternate option for function hook: https://github.com/kubo/plthook
Have not tested, but both seem like they should work. With hotpatch (subhook) you use dlsym to get the function value and then patch it. With plthook you replace the entry in PLT table instead.

Comment: @1110101001 Thanks. This is all looking outside my ability range unfortunately (I know _just_ enough Objective C to write very simple SIMBL plugins.) Ah well... thanks for looking. I'd love to learn how you were able to reverse engineer this stuff, if you know of any resources.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I don't think it should be too hard: you don't really need objective-C knowledge at all, you only need knowledge of C (which if you don't already know, you should pick up since it's useful for reverse engineering in general).  If you go the simbl plugin route, using the libraries mentioned above if everything goes right it should only be ~5 lines of code. I put pseudocode here https://pastebin.com/raw/8YGjPDNL

Comment: If you use ld_preload, it's even easier. You don't need external library, you can just declare the method you want to override and let the linker do it for you. Pseudocode like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/zSuz6vLG

Comment: For reverse engineering I just used Hopper. For the stuff about osx internals and function hooking, etc., part of it is knowledge from studying system internals (Jonathan Levin's book has lots of good knowledge and tidbits), part of it is tricks you pick up after some exposure.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I was curious and since the pseudocode was 95% of the way there, I implemented it. Can you try this? https://pastebin.com/raw/EUbx7zig

Compile via `gcc -framework AppKit -framework Foundation -o dicthook.dylib -dynamiclib file.m`
Load via `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=dicthook.dylib /Applications/Dictionary.app/Contents/MacOS/Dictionary`

Comment: @1110101001 You're awesome, that totally worked! Thank you!

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Great! You can take it from there and polish the implementation. You can avoid the `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE` by declaring the interpose segment in the mach-o library: https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-239.3/include/mach-o/dyld-interposing.h

Then all you do is just modify the plist to set the DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARY env var. Idk if you care about code signing, but that'll break if you modify the plist. Alternatively create your own wrapper app which sets the env and calls dictionary.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous and still want to use SIMBL, then you can try one of the function hooker libraries I mentioned above. That way you don't break code-signing. If you were on 10.10+ you could have used `dyld_dynamic_interpose` which allows you to patch things at runtime.

Comment: (Extra challenge:  Only dylibs loaded via DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES can perform interposing. In the absence of `dyld_dynamic_interpose`, you can still simulate this behavior natively via dyld by using `loadFromMemory` to dynamically load a dylib and then calling "registerInterposing". That provides you the tools to dynamically interpose purely via SIMBL injection and without patching addresses. Refer to https://debugtrap.com/2016/11/14/library-memory-loading/)

Comment: @1110101001 Do you mind if I do a writeup for the answer box?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy feel free to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This phenomenon is not unique to Big Sur—it likely dates back to when the Dictionary application was first introduced in Tiger. [@1110101001](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/104605/1110101001) did some reverse engineering to figure out what's going on.

`DictionaryServices.framework` makes network connections via the now-deprecated `CFHTTPStream`. According to [an Apple engineer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/69452?answerId=230641022#230641022) and [Apple's own code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-128.2/Headers/CFHTTPStream.h.auto.html), any software which uses `CFHTTPStream` will ignore the system's proxy settings, unless the developer goes out of their way to add a few extra lines of code.

To fix this problem, we'll need to inject some code which does what the original developers did not—tell the app to apply the system's proxy settings before running `CFHTTPStream`.

First, compile the following code (e.g. `clang -framework AppKit -framework Foundation -o ProxyFix.dylib -dynamiclib /path/to/code.m`) to create a library we can inject. This was also mostly written by 1110101001; I tweaked it to work with apps that use two-level namespaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

#define DYLD_INTERPOSE(_replacement,_replacee) \
    __attribute__((used)) static struct{ const void* replacement; const void* replacee; } _interpose_##_replacee \
                __attribute__ ((section ("__DATA,__interpose"))) = { (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacement, (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacee };

CFReadStreamRef myCFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(CFAllocatorRef alloc, CFHTTPMessageRef request) {
    printf("Injected ProxyFix!\n");
    CFReadStreamRef ref = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(alloc, request);
    CFDictionaryRef systemProxyDict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings();
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(ref, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy, systemProxyDict);
    return ref;
}

DYLD_INTERPOSE(myCFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest, CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest);
```

We now need to insert this library into the Dictionary application. Luckily, macOS comes with a built-in mechanism for injecting code in the form of `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. If you, like me, are running an ancient and lovably-hackable version of macOS such as 10.9, all you need to do is run your app after setting this environmental variable. For example, run in Terminal:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/path/to/ProxyFix.dylib /Applications/Dictionary.app/Contents/MacOS/Dictionary
```

If you're running macOS 10.6 or below, or if the application isn't code signed (possibly because ***you*** removed the code signature via [optool](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool) or similar), you can also add this environment variable to the app's Info.plist, so that the library is injected automatically.

```
defaults write /Applications/Dictionary.app/Contents/Info LSEnvironment -dict DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES @executable_path/../Frameworks/ProxyFix.dylib
```

Unfortunately, newer versions of macOS have additional security features to prevent code injection. Starting with 10.11, you will need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection) in order to use `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. On the newest OS's such as Big Sur, you may (or may not) need to take further steps as well, such as disabling AMFI—I'm not entirely familiar with all of the new security checks Apple has layered on in recent years.

---

<sub>P.S. If you're running 10.6 – 10.9, I wrapped this up into a little installer which helps you set up a proxy, and then applies the above patch to the Dictionary app. Without the aid of a proxy, the Dictionary app's Wikipedia functionality no longer works at all on these systems. https://jonathanalland.com/downloads/wowfunhappy-https-proxy.dmg</sub>