# "Wikipedia" dictionary does not work even when proxy is set

Tags: macos, network, vpn, dictionary, proxy

I'm in China, so wikipedia is blocked. However, before the English wikipedia is blocked, using wikipedia dictionary already gives "wikipedia server is currently unavailable". The wikipedia dictionary still shows "wikipedia server is currently unavailable" when I turn on a VPN, configure a proxy, and went to school where wikipedia can be opened in the browser (so unblocked by a VPN). Why is this the case? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Dictionary app is not coded to respect the system proxy settings. You can fix it by injecting a few lines of code (as I do on my Mac), but security features in recent macOS releases will (ironically) get in the way, unless you also take the large step of turning those off. See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406462/macos-big-sur-dictionary-app-doesnt-use-system-proxy/